# Is there an Inflate/Deflate Mesh option in Blender?

Tags: modeling

I want to know if there is a tool that I can use to inflate a mesh like a balloon or a cube or anything else. And the same question, just for deflate, so a cube goes in on itself (collapses).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (Shrink/Fatten) command will kind of "inflate" the object.

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

And using a negative value:

[image: negative deflate]

Comment: This is great, but can you animate this if you're in Edit?

Answer (score 16):

[CharlesL's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18659/12) is the closest thing to what you ask but adding this as it can produce some interesting results. You could experiment with the *Simple Deform* modifier set to *Stretch* and adjust the factor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: (Probably the least constructive comment I will ever make:) Lol squishy

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cast modifier to move the mesh towards a sphere (or other shape). It doesn't add any vertices, so if you're working with a simple mesh you might need to add a Remesh modifier before the Cast to give you enough vertices to work with.

[image: Default cube with and without Remesh and Cast modifiers applied]