# How do I model a transfusion blood bag in Blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have been trying to model this asset for a few days but I cannot get it right.

[image]
As everybody can see in the image above (thanks to Jachym Michal) for modeling this object I used an image reference and a grid. 
With my mesh as it is I have encontered with two mayor problems:

1. I have got the general shape down but with that messy topology I can't extrude it.
2. I have modeled the tubes of this thing (the cylindrical object that appear on the image) but I don't know how to joint it to the grid mesh.

For what I got it could be saved or should I start from scratch?

I hope that someone can help me out.

Postdata: I have attached the blend file for anyone who wants it.
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Thanks for sharing your file. Please also add some images to your post, and specify what part causes you trouble. That will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: I can't add an image at the moment. But with the blend file you will see clearly where i'm stuck on. I just used a reference pic and a grid mesh which I subdivided the verts to get the shape. But when I want to extrude it, its messy and I dont know how to add the little tubes at the end of grid.

Comment: Without an image, its hard to tell, but you might be interested in a variation on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160675/35559)

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: Well.. Thanks @Robin Betts for offering a solution. Although I'm still stuck on how to model it. As everyone can see what mesh i have. I hoped to see someone tell me if I what I had could turn into the image renference (Thanks to the person who added the screenshot to the post). Oh well another question of mine without answer...

Comment: I have modificated my post. I hope that someone can reopen it or should I post another one?

Comment: @xscx nope posting another because the first got closed is not the right way to go about questions. Your edit makes this question *much* better. Reopened for you.

Comment: @David thank you!. I hope that someone will find a solution to my problem.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18658/is-there-an-inflate-deflate-mesh-option-in-blender and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shrink-fatten.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some tips for modeling a very simple blood bag.

1) Use *Subdivision modifier* to get that smooth shape.
2) Use *Mirror modifier* for perfect symmetry.
3) Keep quads everywhere, so you can use loop cuts

[image]

**1) Inner and outer shape**
- start with a simple plane and create the inner shape
- add loopcuts, move vertices.
- use Subdivision modifier to get the smooth shape.
- Use *Mirror modifier* for perfect symmetry and to save time.
[image]

- use the same approach to create the outer shape
- make sure it connects nicely to the inner shape and there are no n-gons

[image]

- position some loopcuts for the tube openings.

[image]

**2) Add some thickness**
We need some thickness to create tube openings.
You can add some loopcuts inside the edge to better support the geometry.
[image]

**3) Create tube openings**  (you can apply the *Mirror modifier* before that)
- add a circle and prepare an empty the loop on your bodybag (by removing the faces inside)
- connect through *Edge > Bridge Edge loops*.
- make sure that the number of vertices is the same. (8 in my case)
- If you want more vertices in your circle, just add more loopcuts.

[image]

Add some loopcuts for sharper edges.
[image]

**Here is the file:**
[image]

And the reference image I used:
[image]